# Capture value from selected or active ul li

Tags: javascript

I have the following code where I am trying to capture the value from whatever is selected from a list (.the results) at any given time:

```
var active = document.querySelector(".hover") ||             document.querySelector(".the_results li");

document.addEventListener("keydown",handler);
document.addEventListener("mouseover",handler);

function handler(e){
console.log(e.which);
    active.classList.remove("hover");
if (e.which == 40){
    active = active.nextElementSibling || active;

    document.getElementById("MyElement").value=(What goes inside here);
}else if (e.which == 38){      
    active = active.previousElementSibling || active;

}else{
    active = e.target;
}
    active.classList.add("hover");

}
```

I need help on this:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").value=(What goes inside here);
```

Thank you for your help in advance, because I have ran out of ideas.

Comment: What do you want to go inside of there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById("MyElement").value = active.innerHTML;`

I also added a condition `if (e.target.tagName === 'LI')`. Here's the entire refactored snippet:

```
function handler(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
    active.classList.remove("hover");
    if (e.which == 40) {
        active = active.nextElementSibling || active;     
    } else if (e.which == 38) {
        active = active.previousElementSibling || active;
    } else {
        active = e.target;
    }
    if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        document.getElementById("MyElement").value = active.innerHTML;
    }
    active.classList.add("hover");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9zXmr/

Comment: HALLELUJAH!! Thank you so much @AlienWebguy!